# ImportError: cannot import name 'People' from partially initialized module 'Contacts.models' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, circular-dependency

I have two models. People and Related Contacts. Related contacts has a foreign key relation from People. I don't understand why I'm getting a circular import yet they are not related to each other.

The error

```
from Miscellaneous.models import PersonContactTypes, Genders
File "D:\Projects\Amicas\Back-End\Miscellaneous\models.py", line 2, in <module>
from Contacts.models import People
ImportError: cannot import name 'People' from partially initialized module 'Contacts.models' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Company model

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    contact_type = models.ForeignKey(CompanyContactTypes, verbose_name='Contact Type', on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Created By", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tenant =  models.ForeignKey(Tenant, verbose_name='Tenant', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

People model

```
from Tenants.models import Tenant
from django.db import models
from Members.models import User
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from Miscellaneous.models import PersonContactTypes, Genders

class People(models.Model):
    contact_type = models.ForeignKey(PersonContactTypes, verbose_name='Contact Type', on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Genders, verbose_name='Gender', on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Created By", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company =  models.ForeignKey(Companies, verbose_name='Company', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tenant =  models.ForeignKey(Tenant, verbose_name='Tenant', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Related Contacts model

```
from django.db import models
from Contacts.models import People
from Tenants.models import Tenant
from Members.models import User

class RelatedContacts(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(People, verbose_name='Name', null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Created By", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    tenant =  models.ForeignKey(Tenant, verbose_name='Tenant', max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Pls remove all those Charfields and Datefields. What do they have to do with your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `"app_label.model_name"` notation. Then you can drop all those import statements. And pls rename some of your stuff:

- upper case app/module/package names (don't do it)
- plural model names (will make people doubt your sanity)
- calling a foreign key field "name" (would have me up in arms, if I had to see this in a review)

```
class Company(models.Model):
    contact_type = models.ForeignKey("CompanyContactType", ...)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("members.User", ...)
    tenant =  models.ForeignKey("tenants.Tenant", ...)

class Person(models.Model):
    contact_type = models.ForeignKey("miscellaneous.PersonContactType", ...)
    gender = models.ForeignKey("miscellaneous.Gender", ...)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("members.User", ...)
    company =  models.ForeignKey("Company", ...)  # from the same module?
    tenant =  models.ForeignKey("tenants.Tenant", ...)

class RelatedContact(models.Model):
    # not much left of the oroginal, sorry
    person = models.ForeignKey("contacts.Person", ...)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey("members.User", ...)
    tenant =  models.ForeignKey("tenants.Tenant", ...)
```

Comment: i have added the missing Company model. Let me implement your suggestions and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: thanks it worked. Would you mind explaining why the circular import error was occurring? I still don't get why it occurred, yet I have been doing imports (the old way of importing at the top) from other models without facing such an issue.